# Size of dynamic array in C doesn't change

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, sizeof, dynamic-arrays

I was getting `realloc(): invalid next size` for a program. So I just coded this to understand what's happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *inp;
    printf("%lu ",sizeof(inp));
    char *res = (char*)malloc(15*sizeof(char*));
    printf("%lu ",sizeof(res));
    res = "hello world";
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(res));
    return 0;
}
```

And surprisingly it outputs `8 8 8`. Can anyone explain why is it like that? Why is it 8 by default? And how `malloc()` effects size of `inp`?

Comment: You have a memory leak in your code, when you assign the string literal to the pointer, you *overwrite* the previous address stored in the pointer and loose the memory you previously allocated. After that a call to `free` or `realloc` will not work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg actually, `inp` was never assigned to begin with. The `malloc` return value is stored in `res` and is not lost, aka no memory leak.

Comment: Also, [in C you should not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Ah, missed that. Well, I'll leave my comment in case the OP desiced to "fix" that assignment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg now your first comment makes sense sir. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sizeof`.returns size in bytes of the object representation of type. Remember sizeof is an operator.

Now sizeof is returning here 8 a constant type of `size_t`

**Why isn't it changing?** because in all tha cases you are using the same type that is `char *`.

Here 8 bytes is the size of the character pointer that is 64 bit.

You can probably have a look at this-

`printf("size of array of 10 int: %d\n"  sizeof(int[10]));`

This will give the output:`40`. 40 bytes.

And `malloc` will never affect the size of a `char*`. It still needs 64 bits to store an address of a dynamically allocated space from heap.

### Is it possible to determine size of dynamically allocated memory in c?

There is no **standard** way to do this. You have to take this overhead on your own. You may find some extensions to the compiler that may accomplish this.

Comment: Are you trying to solve a problem in C language using C++ constructs?  What the hell means `"size of array of 10 int:" << sizeof(int[10]) << '\n'` in C ????????????  Could you give an explanation for python language instead?  (look at the tags, please)

Comment: @LuisColorado.: I myself ran the code in C++,then just post the line..sorry I will correct it. thx for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof(inp)` gives you the size of pointer (8 bytes, 64-bits), not the storage under that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(inp)` in your case is `sizeof(pointer)` and hence `sizeof(char-pointer)` on your system is 8 bytes which is a constant. While allocating memory using `malloc()` you would have specified the size so why do you need to get the size of the allocated space again?

And I see `res` is being initialized and not `inp`

Answer (score -1):

*******EDIT******* : The below post was written before the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29391494/revisions) of the question.

You're missing `stdlib.h`, to the most, for function `malloc()` to work properly. After that,

**Point 1:**

```
char *res = (char*)malloc(15*sizeof(char*));
```

should be

```
char *res = malloc(15);   //will also issue warning to resolve missing stdlib.h
```

Point no note: you should be allocating memory for `char`s, not `char *`s. Then , you should write `sizeof(char)`, not `sizeof(char *)`. Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1 in `C`. So, can omit that part.

Please read: [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

**Point 2:**

strings are not supposed to be *assigned* to already `malloc()`ed pointers. use `strcpy()` instead.

```
 inp = "hello world";
```

should be

```
strcpy(inp, "hello world");
```

Otherwise, you'll overwrite the previously allocated memory, returned by `malloc()`. The *assignment* will overwrite the memory location held by `inp`, causing memory leak.

**Point 3.**

`sizeof()` operator returns a value of `size_t`. To print that, you need `%zu` format specifier.

Related, from `C11` standard document, chapter `§7.21.6.1`, paragraph 7,

> z
>
> Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a
>   size_t or the corresponding signed integer type argument; or that a
>   following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a signed integer type
>   corresponding to size_t argument.

---

Then, to answer the query about the output, in all the cases, you're printing `sizeof(inp)` which is essentially `sizeof(char *)` and that value is fixed for a particular platform (`8`, in your case).

Just FYI, `sizeof()` is an operator, it's not a function. It returns the *size* of the datatype, not the *amount of space pointed by the variable*.

Comment: true statements, but does not answer the question.

Comment: @abelenky Well, does it now?